# HQL - INSERT data to one table with mysql ,hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

```
 public static int add_Book(String title, String auth_name, String publisher, String genre) { 
     Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction(); 
    Query query = session.createQuery
             ("INSERT INTO Book(title,auth_name,publisher,genre)"
                    + "SELECT "+title+", "+auth_name+", "+publisher+", "+genre); 
     tx.commit(); 
     return query.executeUpdate();
```

and this error

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode   +-[IDENT] IdentNode:
>   'q' {originalText=q}...

'q' is JTextField data

insert 'q' to 'title'

... Help would BE appreciated..

Comment: If you want to insert data, why there is a `SELECT` instead of `VALUES` ...

Comment: I agree with @foxdie. One more thing, please use parameter binding.

Comment: Initially query sys.   Query query = session.createQuery("INSERT INTO book(title,auth_name,Publisher,Genre,book_id) values('"+title+"','"+auth_name+"','"+publisher+"','"+genre+"','"+book_id+"'");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer of @v.ladynev is good but you can also try like this :

```
 public static void addBook(String title, String authName, String publisher, String genre) { 

Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction tx = null;
// create book Object
Book book = new Book();
book.setTitle(title);
book.setAuthName(authName);
book.setPublisher(publisher);
book.setGenre(genre);

try {
 tx = session.beginTransaction();
 // Save the book to database
 session.save(book); 
 tx.commit();
 }catch(Exception e){
    if (tx!=null) {
     tx.rollback();}
  e.printStackTrace(); 
 }finally{
 // close your session
 session.close();
 }
}
```

Use at least the Bean class to code "cleanly". We use the query only in special cases, otherwise we must at most avoid it in the code or use at least bundle resources. 
Anything else checks that in your `Book` bean class you have`setAuthName` and not `setAuth_Name`.

Comment: You didn't close a session, not rollback a transaction on an exception etc.

Comment: I updated. I didn't say that your solution is bad on the contrary, the problem is that it doesn't manage to put it to execution. For a very simple reason, he doesn't understand it. That's why I showed him a more detailed method because simplified code requires some experience.

Comment: I agree with "simplified" code etc. You need a transaction, `rollback` and this is `e.getMessage()` useless. Better to rethrow an exception after rollback https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/fluent-hibernate-core/src/main/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/cfg/HibernateSessionFactory.java#L47

Comment: I updated again thanks @v.ladynev, BTW your API looks amazing.

Comment: Okay. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Just do it

```
public static void addBook(String title, String authName, String publisher, String genre) { 
    session.save(new Book(title, authName, publisher, genre));
}
```

Obviously, you should wrap that method with session/transaction control code.

And, please, always use Java Naming Convention!
`auth_name, add_Book` are incorrect names — use `authName, addBook` instead.

Comment: How do I change auth_name?

Comment: I agree with @v.ladynev use the camel case like `authName` change it in the method.

Comment: @sjh You should use `authName`. Always use names that way. This is the most important thing.

Comment: How do I add save () to the top source?

Comment: i try this but I get an error.          Query query = session.createQuery("INSERT INTO Book(title,auth_name,publisher,genre) values('"+title+"','"+authname+"','"+publisher+"','"+genre+"')");   is this error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: values near line 1, column 51 [INSERT INTO Book(title,auth_name,publisher,genre) values('qq','ww','ee','rr')]

Comment: @sjh You didn't try. You should remove your code with insert.